# Llamada a Ajax no hace nada

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código, pero al momento de hacer click en el botón "Siguiente", nada sucede, no encuentro cual seria mi error.

**javascript**

```
$("#btnSigModif").click(function(){

    $.post("../Logica/getdataCargarDatosPreIns.php", {"NroSol":$("#NroSol").val()}, function(data){


        if(data.nombres){

            $("#nombres").val(data.nombres);

        }else{
            $("#nombres").val("error");
        }

    },"json");

    $("#datos").show('slow');
});
```

**getdataCargarDatosPreIns.php**

```
<?php
  $NroSol=$_POST["NroSol"];
  echo json_encode(array(
    "nombres"=>"si hay datos"
  );
?>
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="NroSol" name="NroSol"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSigModif" value="SIGUIENTE"/>

<div id="datos">
  <input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" />
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste qué te arroja el navegador? ¿viste en la pestaña network del developer tools de tu navegador el código y/o mensaje de error? Además, no debes usar rutas absolutas para hacer tus peticiones AJAX, usa rutas relativas: `/Logica/getdata....`.

Comment: Por favor, antes de preguntar porqué no funciona tu código, revisa el log de error de php asi como la respuesta devuelta por el navegador en la llamada AJAX. Si lo hubieras hecho el mensaje de error te habría indicado el motivo de que no funcione.

Comment: claro, ya me fije todo eso, no me muestra ningun error, sino no hubiese preguntado, saludos

Comment: y que debería ocurrir al presionar el botón siguiente? Has verificado si el `if(data.nombres){ ... }` es `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu error esta en esta línea.

```
 echo json_encode(array(
   "nombres"=>"si hay datos"
    );
```

No estás cerrando la función json_encode.

Deberia ser asi:

```
 echo json_encode(array(
   "nombres"=>"si hay datos"
   ));
```

Aqui te dejo el ejemplo con ajax.

```
$('#btnSigModif').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Logica/getdataCargarDatosPreIns.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { NroSol: $("#NroSol").val() },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.nombres){
                $("#nombres").val(data.nombres);
            }else{
                $("#nombres").val("error");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#datos").show('slow');
});
```

Comment: gracias, ya lo corregí pero hay algo mas, no entra directamente al .post y nose cual puede ser la razon, ademas q no entiendo mucho ajax

Comment: como? bueno te voy a dejar un ejemplo con la función ajax.

Answer (score 1):

En el codigo php prueba a hacer esto:

```
$NroSol = $_POST["NroSol"];

var_dump($NroSol);
```

Asi puedes saber mostraria el contenido de la variable y puedes saber si funciona correctamente

Y tambien para ver si la conexión ajax funciona bien, prueba a utilizar la consola de red del navegador y te muestra todas las peticiones

O puedes probar tambien de esta forma:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```